# React Native app not building for Android - SyntaxError: \u can only be followed by a Unicode character sequence

Tags: android, react-native

My App is running fine on iOS but will not run on Android. I spent ages last week getting it working, and thought it was , and the problem has returned.

[image]

Logs show [image]

Full logs here in case there is other stuff relevant. https://pastebin.com/by6uCmPW

```
SyntaxError: \u can only be followed by a Unicode character sequence
```

When I reload I then get a white screen, no errors are shown, and I can't get past this, and it does not change whether i connect to the debugger or not.

[image]

I've looked at the source and the error is coming from the following line

[image]

Which is this from the React Native source https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a974c140db605ecbdf8d3faa7a079b7e2dcebb09/Libraries/ReactNative/YellowBox.js#L263

After refreshing, I get the following error in logcat, although nothing in the emulator.

> 06-14 13:52:10.467: E/art(2691): No implementation found for
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.Inspector
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.Inspector.instance() (tried
>   Java_com_facebook_react_bridge_Inspector_instance and
>   Java_com_facebook_react_bridge_Inspector_instance__)

Comment: It seems that your current unicode character format is not acceptable in your android build. Have you tried changing its format from `'\u{25BC}'` to  `'\u25BC'` which is another valid format for unicode characters?

Comment: @Merka Any ideas where to change it? I've tried your suggestion and updated directly the `YellowBox.js` but it doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had the same issue and this is the solution I came up with that in order to make it work, I've added `console.disableYellowBox = true;` to `index.android.js` after the all imports lines.

---

**As per React Native docs**

YellowBoxes can be disabled during development by using `console.disableYellowBox = true;`. Specific warnings can be ignored programmatically by setting an array of prefixes that should be ignored: `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: ...'];`.

> RedBoxes and YellowBoxes are automatically disabled in release (production) builds.

---

It's not an ideal workaround and probably still require some tinkering but by doing that I was able to compile the app.

Then in order to go a couple of steps deeper, I removed the recent addings (`console.disableYellowBox = true;` from `index.android.js`) and 
replaced `{stacktraceVisible ? '\u{25BC}' : '\u{25B6}'} Stacktrace` from `\src\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js`
with one of those next things:

- `{stacktraceVisible ? '\u25BC' : '\u25B6'} Stacktrace`
- `{stacktraceVisible ? '-' : '-'} Stacktrace`

It seems to fix the problem but not sure how elegant this way is and how you would be able to update every time after `yarn` or `npm i`.

Answer (score 0):

What oddly worked for me was moving the entire project into another folder